# How to decide router-outlet programatically using angular6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-routing, angular-router

i have to show two different pages, ie. before login and after login page

**before login page**

> This will only show the home page and a login button

**after login page**

> this will display a common-template page which will have all the menu

now for this, i have two pages, one with router-oulet for displaying simple page with no menu bar and the other with router-outlet surrounded by menu bars. but my problem is, i am not able to decide which page will go on which router-outlet, how can i choose the router-outlet programatically for the page, is there a different way to do it, please advice

--router-outlet-A

```
--home page

--login page
```

--router-outlet-B

```
--product page

--testimonial page
```

**UPDATE:**

i am looking for something like this

```
<router-outlet #templateA></router-outlet> 
<router-outlet #templateB></router-outlet>

decideOnTemplate() {
    if(user-not-logged-in) {
        this.templateA.send(this.page)
    } else {
        this.templateB.send(this.page)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Lijin Durairaj. This kind of problem can be easily solved by using auth guards if the user is authorized to navigate to product or testimonial page otherwise redirect to the login page using auth guards.

Comment: no, my problem is not authorization/authentication, i want to place the page into one of the router programatically, how can i do that?

Comment: is there really a need for that? i have a feeling that for that complexity, its a bit over complicating. Cant you just have 2 routes, one route with login button + homepage( lets call it landing component) and the other one product + testimonial ( lets call it panel component). Then you can decide after login to which component to route to. Router-outlets are used only to navigate trough children of a component so that the parent isnt rerendered

Comment: I didnt downvote your question. I think there is no need for router-outlets in the example given.

Comment: Every outlet has it's own set of routes. Different outlet routes can't be mixed up easily. If you're not going to show two pages at the same time, you definitely don't need two outlets on the same page. Conditional rendering is all you need in order to provide your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the basic steps for Routing, which is provided on this site https://dzone.com/articles/angular-5-material-design-login-application

The above points can be summarized like this.

Step 1: Develop 2 components, Login component and Page Component along with a Setting Component naming as app.settings.ts( here we can create a class, which contains variables for Sidenavbar, fixed header)

```
mport { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Settings } from './app.settings.model';

@Injectable()
export class AppSettings {
    public settings = new Settings(
        true,       // fixedHeader
        true,       // sidenavIsOpened
    );
}
```

Step 2: With the help of the above settings(here sidenavIsOpened, which is user defined) we can handle the navbar div's by *ngIf.

```
  <mat-sidenav *ngIf="settings.sidenavIsOpened">
        <app-sidenav></app-sidenav> // here we can give our pages details.
    </mat-sidenav>
```

Refer this to Lazy Routing, which is similar to your idea https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Comment: this is not feasible, as i have to show and hide more than one div and it would be more complicated and would be difficult to maintain

Comment: bro, instead of div's u can use selectors (say <product *ngIf="settings.sidenavIsOpened"></product>)to maintain that.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.you can do that !!! If you want to navigate user to your product page after successful authentication your can paste below logic in you app.component.ts

```
constuctor(private router: Router)

login(){
<--- Your logic --->
this.router.navigate(['/product-page']);
}

Hope this will help.
```

Comment: i have already update that this is not related to user authentication or authorization, i want to decide on the router-outlet to render the page